# Java - Spring Boot: Firmar XML electrónicamente

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, firma-digital

Estoy generando un archivo XML con una factura electronica (FacturaE) y lo siguiente que tengo que hacer es permitir que se firme con Firma Electrónica.

Mi problema es que no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo. No sé por dónde empezar.

He estado investigando en este [enlace](http://sedeaplicaciones2.minetur.gob.es/FacturaE/politica_de_firma_formato_facturae_v3_1.pdf) y parece que los campos que tengo que añadir en el XML son estos:

```
<ds:Signature >
    <ds:SignedInfo/>
    <ds:SignatureValue/>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate/>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:Object>
        <xades:QualifyingProperties>
            <xades:SignedProperties>
                <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                    <xades:SigningTime />
                    <xades:SigningCertificate/>?
                    <xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier/>
                    <xades:SignerRole/>?
                </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
            </xades:SignedProperties>
            <xades:UnSignedProperties/>
        </xades:QualifyingProperties>
</ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>
```

El principal problema es que no sé de dónde sacar esa información. ¿vendrá en un archivo de "Certificado digital" que debo leer? ¿La debe introducir el usuario a mano?

Agradecería cualquier rayito de luz sobre todo esto.

Edito para ser más específico:

Estoy desarrollando un servicio en Java que genera facturas electrónicas en formato FacturaE. Como resultado, el usuario descarga finalmente una factura en formato XML.

Lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario tenga la posibilidad de firmar digitalmente el archivo XML antes de generarlo, sin necesidad de descargar un XML no firmado, ir a "Autofirma" y firmarlo desde allí.

Comment: Para responder ésta pregunta necesitas especificar. Comienza por [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firma_digital).

Comment: Mis disculpas si no me he explicado bien. Edito el post original.

Comment: Y cómo estás generando el archivo? Lo importante es que tengas claro qué es firmar electrónicamente y ahí será trivial entender lo que tienes que aplicarle a la factura

Comment: El archivo lo estoy generando desde Java, usando JAVAX. Una vez generado lo devuelvo a la parte de front y ellos generan el archivo. A medida que sigo investigando, mi mayor duda es de dónde voy a sacar la información necesaria para rellenar la parte de "Signature" del XML. La proporcionará el usuario a través de un formulario o, lo que me parece más probable, ¿Deberé leer la información contenida en un archivo de certificado digital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La firma que quieres incluir en el XML va a depender del estándar que quieras utilizar. Por el ejemplo que colocas parecería ser XML-DSIG.
Y pues para eso necesitas una librería, porque hacerlo desde cero es mucho trabajo. Te recomendaría revisar https://santuario.apache.org/

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! En cuanto lo tenga implementado posteo mi solución.